# ISO8601 format - Amazon Web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, iso8601

I am receiving the following error: 'Timestamp 2015-06-29T15%3A08%3A27Z must be in ISO8601 format' I have double checked and I believe it is in IS08601 format (then urlencoded)

When I have matched the format again the one created within https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html it seems to be the same.

Any idea?

1. Mine:      2015-06-29T15%3A08%3A27Z
2. Theirs: 2015-06-29T15%3A12%3A47Z

Thanks,

Clare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure what the issue was, however I found this on another site (relating to Amazon timespan issue. This did solve my issue.

```
public static string ConvertDateToString(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime utcTime;

        if (date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
        {
            utcTime = new DateTime(
                date.Year,
                date.Month,
                date.Day,
                date.Hour,
                date.Minute,
                date.Second,
                date.Millisecond,
                DateTimeKind.Local).ToUniversalTime();
        }
        else
        {
            utcTime = date;
        }

        return utcTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd\\THH:mm:ss.fff\\Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: is this meant as an answer or to indicate the code you are creating? I see the `.ToString` format at the end does not match the string you gave as 'Mine'.

Comment: This is what i used in the end to create the timespan